# C# Equivalent to ActionScript3's BitmapData

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

is there any C# equivalent to ActionScript3's BitmapData?
I want to port the "as3delauny" library into C#. But I really don´t find any class in C# which has similar methods...

Or is there any existing port out there?

Thanks
R

Answer (score 2):

Bitmap and its [Bitmap.LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) is the one you are likely looking for if you need raw image data manipulation part.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any "hitTest" method-equivalent?

Comment: @Razer no. I'd recommend searching if someone already created complete port. There is no method equivalent to hitTest in .Net Framework as far as I know.

Comment: That´s bad ... Google doesn´t find any port. Not even theme related links :-/